# What is all the "housekeeping" that has to be done in a FXML app?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm currently trying to convert a JavaFX app to a FXML app(work requirements), and I've been running in circles for a while now. I understand the basic principle (User interface and the backend workings defined separately), but all the hoop-jumping, technicalities,  workarounds, all those initialize()s, loaders, start()s, launch()s, controllers, injections and whatnot are getting a bit over my head. The app in its current state spits out a compile time error that I couldn't divine anything out of if my life depended on it, but I vaguely suspect it leads somewhere into the underlying murk of the whole FXMLLoader thing.

This is no way to work. The tutorials only explain a part of it each, and my current modus operandi is still copying over/slightly modifying bits of code I find wherever and hoping it will work somehow, rather than actually understanding the principle and taking well-reasoned steps towards a clear goal. Is there a list of everything I need to do to make a FXML app work, or some clear explanation of how it all comes together?

Comment: Maybe the second half of my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857389/how-to-pass-data-from-java-to-fxml/33857574#33857574 will help a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of things required to do in the order they are typically done:

1. Define UI in an FXML file (say ui.fxml)
2. Write a controller class for the given FXML which contains JavaFX fields with @FXML annotation, to be injected from the above FXML.
3. Go back to FXML file and add fx:controller="fullpackagename.ControllerName"
4. Implement `public void initialize()` if necessary. This will be called after injection. Mind the method signature, must be exactly the same.
5. Write an entry point, typically `SomethingApp extends Application`. In the overriden `start()` during `Scene` object construction pass the following as root node to the scene - `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui.fxml"))`.

Here's a short working [example](https://github.com/AlmasB/NativeJFX/tree/master/src/main). The example assumes you are familiar with the Maven directory structure. If not, then all 3 files, namely App, Controller, ui.fxml must be in the same package, for FXMLLoader to be able to locate it.